# Porting access(2) Linux system call to boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, boost-filesystem

Currently, I have an application which I am porting from Linux to Windows.  I would prefer to use boost where possible.

I currently have the following snippet which I want to port, which is pretty self-explanatory.

```
return access(backupFile.c_str(), R_OK) == 0;
```

The problem is that is seems like boost::filesystem does not have a direct equivalent.  That is, I can do the following:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

if (!fs::is_regular_file(filename, ec))
    return false;

fs::file_status s = fs::status(filename);

// Which permissions should I be testing for?
if (s.permissions() == ???)
```

The permissions() enum can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Enum-perms). However, I as I read it, it is not a direct trananslation, as I would have to test to see if I am in the applicable group and if the group's permissions are also available.

Is there an easier way? Is my interpretation on the behavior correct?

(Of course, I can always attempt to open the file for reading, but that is not the goal of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are porting to windows, according to Microsoft [_access()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx) second parameter is:

```
00 Existence only
02 Write-only
04 Read-only
06 Read and write
```

so, I think you should use boost permissions that match the above taking into account the following from the permissions reference link:

```
Windows: All permissions except write are currently ignored. There is only a single
write permission; setting write permission for owner, group, or others sets write
permission for all, and removing write permission for owner, group, or others removes
write permission for all.
```

Alternatively, you may want to continue using Windows version of access() (_access() for MS compilers) with the parameters Microsoft specifies.

Another class you may want to look into is ATL [CAccessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f42z4h7d.aspx)

Comment: I haven't worked with CE for many years, I don't remember this one, but if late versions do not have it, there is also GetFileAttributes() API you may want to check :)

Comment: Done. Solves my problem.

Comment: In MSVC C Standard Library implementation, even today, `_access` and all its derivatives do not verify the `04 Read-only` access mode at all: look into its source code or just revoke read access from a file and check what `_access` returns.